# Converting list of lists to dataframe in R, error showing <int[1]>

Tags: r, dataframe

I have data that looks like the first two code blocks below.
It is from the league of legends API.
I want it to be in the format of a dataframe so I can work with it easily.

```
str(parsed) #results in the output below (only copy pasted list 1 of 134)

List of 134
 $ :List of 9
  ..$ championId                  : int 4
  ..$ championLevel               : int 7
  ..$ championPoints              : int 862802
  ..$ lastPlayTime                : num 1.59e+12
  ..$ championPointsSinceLastLevel: int 841202
  ..$ championPointsUntilNextLevel: int 0
  ..$ chestGranted                : logi TRUE
  ..$ tokensEarned                : int 0
  ..$ summonerId                  : chr "XrwVJcVcHXeuPEIxjYEBXCrmNy7oWeWpnzrM-jOLD94BYl4"
```

```
parsed #results in output below (only copy pasted 1 out of 134)

[[1]]
[[1]]$championId
[1] 4

[[1]]$championLevel
[1] 7

[[1]]$championPoints
[1] 862802

[[1]]$lastPlayTime
[1] 1.593139e+12

[[1]]$championPointsSinceLastLevel
[1] 841202

[[1]]$championPointsUntilNextLevel
[1] 0

[[1]]$chestGranted
[1] TRUE

[[1]]$tokensEarned
[1] 0

[[1]]$summonerId
[1] "XrwVJcVcHXeuPEIxjYEBXCrmNy7oWeWpnzrM-jOLD94BYl4"
```

This basically gave me the output I wanted, except the data.frame has <int [1]> in it or <dbl [1]> and I cannot figure out what it means. Screenshot below for clarity

https://i.stack.imgur.com/06bjG.png

```
LoL_API_ROW_NAMES <- c("championID", "championLevel", "championPoints", "lastPlayTime", "championPointsSinceLastLevel",  "championPointsUntilNextLevel", "chestGranted", "tokensEarned", "summonerId")
LOL_API_MATRIX <- matrix(as.data.frame(parsed),nrow = 134, ncol = 9, byrow = TRUE,dimnames = list(1:134, LoL_API_ROW_NAMES))
as.data.frame(LOL_API_MATRIX)
```

Just FYI, I also tried each of the codes below, but none of them worked.

```
as.data.frame(parsed)
as_tibble(parsed)
lapply(parsed, as.data.frame) 
sapply(parsed, as.data.frame)
str(sapply(parsed,as.data.frame))
```

How can I convert my list to a dataframe?

Comment: What do you get when you try `lapply(parsed, as.data.frame)`

Comment: If your `parsed` is `parsed <- list(list(championId = 9, championLevel = 7), list(championId = 5, championLevel = 4))` then `do.call(rbind, lapply(parsed, as.data.frame))` works for me

Comment: Or with `library(purrr);map_dfr(parsed, as_tibble)`

Comment: @akrun              When I try lapply(parsed, as.data.frame) it makes 134 different data frames. The second comment failed because it said the "First argument must be a character string". I got it working though, so I will post the answer that I figured out

Comment: Sorry, my understasnding was that it is nested list of vectors.  If it is not, then you may need to show a small reproducible example that shows the issue.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to get it to work, it was the unlist command that I had not found before.

```
LoL_API_ROW_NAMES <- c("championID", "championLevel", "championPoints", "lastPlayTime", "championPointsSinceLastLevel",  "championPointsUntilNextLevel", "chestGranted", "tokensEarned", "summonerId")
LOL_API_MATRIX2 <- matrix(unlist(parsed), nrow = 134, ncol = 9, byrow = TRUE, dimnames = list(1:134, LoL_API_ROW_NAMES))
LOL_API_DF <- as.data.frame(LOL_API_MATRIX2)
```

Comment: Note that when you do `unlist`, it assumes that the `list` elements are of the same type and have the same number of observations.  Otherwise, it can have some issues in type because everything is now converted to character